# Shared Facebook video is not displayed inline in wall posts for HTTPS users

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I have an application with a Like button. Once I click Like, a post, including a video link,  goes to my facebook wall.
If I turn off facebook security (all FB pages are opened through insecure http), i can play video embedded into my facebook wall. But once security is on clicking my video thumbnail opens a new tab instead of embedded player.

How can I make video play the same way regardless facebook security.

Looks like it's possible: YouTube pages have essentially the same OGraph tabs included, but their player always opens embedded into my wall regardless FB security settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may need to specify the HTTPS source of your video, see here:
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/602/

and the docs:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/#audiovideo

An example of how to specify the secure URL is:
`<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://secure.example.com/awesome.swf"/>`

I think youtube is a special case and everyone else needs to manually specify the HTTPS URL in order for the content to be displayed inline for HTTPS users