# Video thumbnail does not have a Play button on Facebook shared links

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

The video links shared via my website on Facebook appear as only images in the shared link; Facebook doesn't seem to recognize the content as video.

I've debugged the URL via Facebook debugger, and every thing appears fine:

`<http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=www.vlikeviral.com%2Fvideos%2Fplay%3Fid%3D10>`

The thumbnail that appears under the link does not have a play button on it. As you can see in the debug details, the appropriate og tags are already present on the page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shared Facebook video is not displayed inline in wall posts for HTTPS users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267543/shared-facebook-video-is-not-displayed-inline-in-wall-posts-for-https-users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing an `og:video` tag pointing to the video source.

See also [Shared Facebook video is not displayed inline in wall posts for HTTPS users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267543/shared-facebook-video-is-not-displayed-inline-in-wall-posts-for-https-users) - you also need to include the HTTPS source if you want users browsing Facebook over HTTPS to see the inline video.

Comment: adding og:video tag does not fix the problem :(

Comment: It's fixed, I don't really know how but, adding a couple of more og tags(video:tag, og:video and fb:app_id) solved the problem. Thanks for providing the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

For video playing Facebook is not considering og:video tag, instead of that it is looking for og:video:secure_url tag
refer-link: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/602/

Answer (score -3):

It is very easy. You can add play button on an image like Facebook play button by using adobe Photoshop. Watch this video you will understand how to add it on the image.
http://mefmor.blogspot.com/2014/08/how-to-add-facebook-play-button-in-your.html